# Plotting Logarithmic and Exp graph in Java

Tags: java, graph

I am doing my coursework on Java and I am stuck in doing the graphs for 3 functions. X-x^2, ln(x-1)-1 and e^x-3x.

I have already tried to set up JFrame with axis and even code for x-x^2 that plots graph for that function.

```
int x,y;
int ax,by;

String s="deba";
String se ="deba";


public Plotfunct1(){ 

    setTitle("Function graph");
    setSize(900,700);
            setLayout(null);

    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);


            x = 30;
    y = 300;



}


    @Override
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawString("Y", 310, 40);
    g.drawString("Y'", 310, 600);
    g.drawString("X", 30, 314);
    g.drawString("X'", 600, 314);
    if(x==300&&y==300){
        g.drawString("Origin(0,0)", 310, 314);
    }
    g.drawLine(300, 30, 300, 600);
    g.drawLine(30,300,600,300);
    if(x>599||y<40){

        x = 30;
        y=300;

    }
    if(x<600&&y>30&&y!=600){

             ax = x-300;
             by = y-300;
              ax++;

              by = (int) (.095*(ax-Math.pow(ax,2))); 
            x=300+ax;
            y=300-by;


        }

    g.fillOval(x, y, 3, 3);
    repaint();





}


}
```

I need to plot the last 2 functions I have tried everything that I could come up with changing the Math.pow to Math.log but then I just get one line

Comment: Show us what you tried and maybe we can help you figure out why it failed.

Comment: I tried changing this line of code by = (int) (.095*(ax-Math.pow(ax,2))); to (Math.log10(x-1)-1) but i got only a line on X axis. The i tried Math.exp(x) then i got no line at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Polygons?

I dont have experience with the Graphics class, but seems like [fillOval()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillOval(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) only draws circles, it does not apply for logarithmic functions.

[Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43970030/graphing-functions) You can add points to the graph using addPoint() on the Polygon, then draw the polygon on the Graphic using drawPolyline(). All you have to do is adjust the formula.

Comment: The problem about that code is that i am using Frame builders and when i open that class using that code in that class it shows me just close button on top and no other contents.